# How to change data type in MongoDB using code to pymongo (Python)

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I upload the csv file to my base. But date and other numeric data are presented as strings. Nowhere can I find information on how to change the field type. Please write an example)

The documents are located in the table in this form

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f3e76dfaca73bedb23ef8a1"
    },
    "Province/State": null,
    "Country/Region": "Afghanistan",
    "Lat": "33.93911",
    "Long": "67.709953",
    "Date": "2020-08-19",
    "Value": "37599",
    "ISO 3166-1 Alpha 3-Codes": "AFG",
    "Region Code": "142",
    "Sub-region Code": "34",
    "Intermediate Region Code": null
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. We can help you better if you post a minimal code snippet for your csv loader.

Comment: You can update field with new value and type, MongoDB doesn't enforce types

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, parse_dates=["Date"], dtype={"Lat": "double", "Value": "int32"}, skiprows=[1])
            df = df.fillna({"Region Code": 0, "Sub-region Code": 0, "Intermediate Region Code": 0})
            df = df.astype({"Region Code": int, "Sub-region Code": int, "Intermediate Region Code": int})
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is when you are parsing the CSV file you get all of the values as strings. Subsequently that's what you end up with in the database.

Most likely you need to manually cast values to the desired type after you loaded them from the CSV file and before inserting into MongoDB.

Comment: While I have achieved this result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63560114/error-import-csv-file-to-mongodb-with-pymongo-pandas