# Error: import CSV file to mongoDB with pymongo (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, pymongo

I have a little code that I want to use to import data. But I just can't specify the attributes for pd.read_csv. Made based on video on Youtube. Absolutely new to this, if you fix the code, I will be very grateful.

My error

```
Collection:  Confirmed_global_narrow
Traceback (most recent call last):

AttributeError: list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

PLS, what am I doing wrong?

```
try:
    import pymongo
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    import pandas as pd
    import json
except Exception as e:
    print("Some Modules are Missing ")


class MongoDB(object):

    def __init__(self, dBName=None, collectionName=None):

        self.dBName = dBName
        self.collectionName = collectionName

        self.client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)

        self.DB = self.client[self.dBName]
        self.collection = self.DB[self.collectionName]
        print("Collection: " ,collectionName) 

    def InsertData(self, path = None, parse_dates = None, dtype = None, skiprows = None):

        df = pd.read_csv(path, parse_dates, dtype, skiprows)
        data = df.to_dict('records')

        self.collection.insert_many(data)
        print("All the Data has been Exported to Mongo DB Server")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    mongodb = MongoDB(dBName = 'CovidModel', collectionName='Confirmed_global_narrow')
    mongodb.InsertData(path = "https://data.humdata.org/hxlproxy/data/download/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global_narrow.csv?dest=data_edit&filter01=merge&merge-url01=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fspreadsheets%2Fd%2Fe%2F2PACX-1vTglKQRXpkKSErDiWG6ycqEth32MY0reMuVGhaslImLjfuLU0EUgyyu2e-3vKDArjqGX7dXEBV8FJ4f%2Fpub%3Fgid%3D1326629740%26single%3Dtrue%26output%3Dcsv&merge-keys01=%23country%2Bname&merge-tags01=%23country%2Bcode%2C%23region%2Bmain%2Bcode%2C%23region%2Bsub%2Bcode%2C%23region%2Bintermediate%2Bcode&filter02=merge&merge-url02=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fspreadsheets%2Fd%2Fe%2F2PACX-1vTglKQRXpkKSErDiWG6ycqEth32MY0reMuVGhaslImLjfuLU0EUgyyu2e-3vKDArjqGX7dXEBV8FJ4f%2Fpub%3Fgid%3D398158223%26single%3Dtrue%26output%3Dcsv&merge-keys02=%23adm1%2Bname&merge-tags02=%23country%2Bcode%2C%23region%2Bmain%2Bcode%2C%23region%2Bsub%2Bcode%2C%23region%2Bintermediate%2Bcode&merge-replace02=on&merge-overwrite02=on&filter03=explode&explode-header-att03=date&explode-value-att03=value&filter04=rename&rename-oldtag04=%23affected%2Bdate&rename-newtag04=%23date&rename-header04=Date&filter05=rename&rename-oldtag05=%23affected%2Bvalue&rename-newtag05=%23affected%2Binfected%2Bvalue%2Bnum&rename-header05=Value&filter06=clean&clean-date-tags06=%23date&filter07=sort&sort-tags07=%23date&sort-reverse07=on&filter08=sort&sort-tags08=%23country%2Bname%2C%23adm1%2Bname&tagger-match-all=on&tagger-default-tag=%23affected%2Blabel&tagger-01-header=province%2Fstate&tagger-01-tag=%23adm1%2Bname&tagger-02-header=country%2Fregion&tagger-02-tag=%23country%2Bname&tagger-03-header=lat&tagger-03-tag=%23geo%2Blat&tagger-04-header=long&tagger-04-tag=%23geo%2Blon&header-row=1&url=https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2FCSSEGISandData%2FCOVID-19%2Fmaster%2Fcsse_covid_19_data%2Fcsse_covid_19_time_series%2Ftime_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv", 
                       parse_dates = ["Date"])
    
    mongodb = MongoDB(dBName = 'CovidModel', collectionName='Beds')
    mongodb.InsertData(path="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hf2000510/infectious_disease_modelling/master/data/beds.csv")
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. To help us help you, please include the full stack trace of your error.

Comment: I suggest reducing the code provided in the question to only the relevant snippet necessary for reproducing the issue.  Specifically, if you don't have class or function definitions, what would the code look like? Can you remove the mongoDB code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing incorrect parameters to `read_csv()`. If you don't specify the parameter names they are passed in the order [as per the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

You can likely fix you issue with:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, parse_dates=parse_dates, dtype=dtype, skiprows=skiprows)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But unfortunately the code doesn't do what I want it to do. The thing is, I need parameters to be executed on import, such as changing the date string to its ISO value, but that doesn't work. `...parse_dates = ["Date"]...` sorry for my English

Comment: Do you still get the AttributeError?

Comment: Oh, no, that's right, I'm looking at the wrong place, thank you very much